# How can I get the content details of a revised text file using Dropbox Core API?

Tags: javascript, api, coffeescript, diff, dropbox

I need my node.js app to fetch the net revised portion of a single text file, using dropbox-js library.

I think I searched the Core API documentation quite thoroughly but I couldn't find the reference I wanted and already checked the following posts.

- [How to get the revision of an item with Dropbox API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601104/how-to-get-the-revision-of-an-item-with-dropbox-api)
- [How can I store the files in my server after picking the files from dropbox with the dropbox Chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923609/how-can-i-store-the-files-in-my-server-after-picking-the-files-from-dropbox-with)

What I am expecting is the actual text content difference between the current revision and the one previously made.

I guess I could just listen for changes using the /longpoll_delta endpoint and manually check for differences using readFile, but I would like to know if there's a much simpler way to achieve this.

*Update: I just realized I can harness the rev or versionTag param when using readFile however it's still fetching the whole text file not the revised content. Here's my code:*

```
module.exports.getFile = (callback) ->
  options = {}
  options.rev = '1942a704479aca'
  client.readFile 'todo.txt', options, (err, data) ->
    if err
      throw err
    callback data
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you're asking for, Dropbox doesn't provide this. Dropbox will give you both versions of the file via the API, but Dropbox doesn't have an API for diffing two text files.

Comment: Thanks @smarx, I have a quick question: could you know of a good workaround to achieve the "diffing feature" which I could start from? I think there will be other people who'd want to do similar things.(extract the true delta)

Comment: You would just download both versions of the file (via [`/files (GET)`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) with the `rev` parameter) and then diff them. E.g., Python has a built-in library for diffing: [`difflib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html).